# derivative proof of $\frac{dx^2}{d x}$ is $2x$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

I am studying for a midterm and I have no idea about how to prove that the derivate of $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$ is equal to $2x$

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der01/der01.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^2+2hx+h^2-x^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}(2x+h)=2x.$$